# Whitespace underneath image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm converting my site from a fixed to responsive layout and using the getskeleton framework. http://jsfiddle.net/L2q750xw/1/

```
 <div class="one-third column">

    <h4>Basic Page</h4>
     <div class="home-box-wrap"><img class="u-max-full-width" src="http://www.aroundtheworldin80jobs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/2013-berlin.jpg"></div>

    <p>This index.html page is a placeholder with the CSS, font and favicon. It's just waiting for you to add some content! If you need some help hit up the <a href="http://www.getskeleton.com">Skeleton    documentation</a>.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
}.home-box-wrap{
width:100%;
height:0%;
 border:2px solid #ff00ff;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding:0px;
 }
.u-max-full-width {
 max-width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box; }
```

All works as expected except for the whitespace underneath images, I can't see a reason for this and have tried removing the padding and adjusting the box height and it should all be normalized.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You basically have two options.

Either change the `vertical-align` property of the `img` element to something other than the default value of `baseline`:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/1cbv2h2h/)

```
.u-max-full-width {
    vertical-align: top;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

---

In some cases, you could also change the `display` of the `img` element from the default value `inline`, to `block`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/dp43gjmk/)

```
.u-max-full-width {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

---

As for why this is happening:

There is reserved whitespace for `inline` elements for [letters such as f, j, p and q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image/5804278#5804278) that extend beyond the height of other letters. By changing the `vertical-align` property of the element to something *other* than the default value of `baseline`, the whitespace is removed. By changing the `display` of the element to `block`, the `vertical-align` property no longer has an effect on the element as it is no longer `inline`.

Comment: plus 1 , well framed answer!

Comment: @tomharrison Mark the answer correct if it answered your question. Click the tick under the votes.

Answer (score 1):

@JoshCrozier has got a nice way out! But I would like to add a cheeky trick that will help you out. Just add a negative `margin-bottom` to all your `img` elements.

```
img{
    margin-bottom:-7px;
}
```

Working fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/L2q750xw/3/

Comment: This isn't always guaranteed to work since the amout of whitespace will vary depending on the size of the font. [See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ymkojrq6/) This is essentially a hack. Why `-7px`?

Comment: @JoshCrozier yup i am aware of that , and -7px by trial and error method ;)

Answer (score 0):

The image is being displayed `inline` and hence your padding:0 rule is not getting applied. Make it a block/inline-block level element

```
.home-box-wrap img  { display:block }
```